# Multiple processes reading from and writing to queues until object attribute is true

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue, multiprocessing

I have an object instance that holds two queues, an input queue and an output queue. The parent process spawns several child processes that work on the queues.

My requirements are:

- it should be possible to fill the input queue at any time (function `fill()` in the code below)
- the child processes should process items from the input queue. If the input queue is empty, they should wait for the input queue to be filled (function `echo()`)
- items should be read from the output queue if it is not empty (function `read()`)
- if a shared shutdown flag (attribute `self._shutdown`) is set to true, all processes should end instead of waiting for queue items

Here is the code I currently have:

**Python 2.7 Minimal Example**

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process, Value
from ctypes import c_bool
from Queue import Empty

class A(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self._shutdown = Value(c_bool, False)
    self._input_queue = Queue()
    self._output_queue = Queue()

  def echo(self):
    while True:
      if self._shutdown.value == True: break
      try:
        item = self._input_queue.get(True, timeout=1)
      except Empty:
        continue
      print "[echo] read from input qeue: ", item
      print "[echo] put into output queue: ", item*2
      self._output_queue.put(item*2)

  def fill(self):
    for item in xrange(1,6):
      print "[fill] put into input queue: ", item
      self._input_queue.put(item)

  def read(self):
    while True:
      if self._shutdown.value == True: break
      try:
        item = self._output_queue.get(True, timeout=1)
      except Empty:
        continue
      print "[read] got from output queue: ", item

a = A()

p1 = Process(target=a.echo)
p2 = Process(target=a.echo)

p1.start()
p2.start()

a.fill()
a.read()
a._shutdown.value = True
```

The output of the script above is correct:

```
[fill] put into input queue:  1
[fill] put into input queue:  2
[fill] put into input queue:  3
[fill] put into input queue:  4
[fill] put into input queue:  5
[echo] read from input qeue:  1
[echo] put into output queue:  2
[echo] read from input qeue:  2
[echo] put into output queue:  4
[echo] read from input qeue:  3
[echo] put into output queue:  6
[read] got from output queue:  2
[echo] read from input qeue:  4
[read] got from output queue:  6
[echo] put into output queue:  8
[echo] read from input qeue:  5
[echo] put into output queue:  10
[read] got from output queue:  8
[read] got from output queue:  4
[read] got from output queue:  10
```

Except that it deadlocks and the process never finishes. It seems that the processes block each other. My question is:

**Why exactly does my code deadlock and what can I do to prevent this?**

Comment: Dont you want to 'break' in `except Empty:` ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer No, because the queue could be filled with items later. In that case, I want the process to wait, unless `self._shutdown.value == True`.

Comment: I assume you're not on Windows(tm) as you don't have `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: @PeterWood No, Mac Os X.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970084/sharing-many-queues-among-processes-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `a.read()` is synchronous call in main thread which causes a forever while loop until `self._shutdown.value` is `True`.You are making it happen on the line under `a.read`.So the line `a._shutdown.value = True` is never executing .Then only the changes will reflect inside `p1` and `p2`.So briefly what happening is `p1(process 1)`, `p2(process 2)` and `read()(main process)` is running forever.

Comment: Exactly, thanks for spotting this! Thank you also for the link to the related question above.